# Can't sort date in SQLite3 Android

Tags: android, date

I have Date field in table created using SQlite. now when I am tring to sort those dates, I shows me wrong answer. I have used "1-January-2001" kind of Format for storing dates. How can I retrieve in descending order of date.
I have values like:

24-June-2013

26-June-2013

13-June-2012

13-June-2013

9-June-2013

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: there is no date type in sqlite ... . you have to store data as "yyyyMMdd" or as [EPOCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to make them sortable

Answer (score 0):

See the following link, sqlite does not have a datatype of date so your cannot handle dates directly like in other db

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the datetime function using the Java wrapper "ContentValues".

you can use :

SQLiteDatabase.execSQL so you can enter a raw SQL query.

```
mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+DATABASE_TABLE+" VALUES (null, datetime()) ");
```

> Or the java date time capabilities :

```
// set the format to sql date time
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put("date_created", dateFormat.format(date));
long rowId = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

Thanks.